# Twilio Speech Recognization: Increase speech pause time when speechTimeout='auto'

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I have set speechTimeout to 'auto', which means Twilio will stop speech recognition when there is a pause in speech. But the pause time is very less and speech recognition stops even if there is a small gap in the speech. Is there any attribute to increase the pause/break time we can set?

```
twiml_response.gather(input='speech', hints='', speechTimeout='auto', action='/test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is currently no way to affect how long the `speechTimeout='auto'` will wait for gaps in speech.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way top handle this without using 'auto'?

Comment: Your alternative is to set a number as the `speechTimeout` and the `<Gather>` will wait for the timeout before it returns.